# Grid rows aren't the (relative) height I set them to

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was working on a UserControl in a View, when I came across this problem:

I set my content grids row heights to be 2*, 1* and 1* with the lines in between set to auto.
Now. The uppermost row has a grid nested in with a TextBlock and a TextBox. The height of the cell is in no way 2*. It looks like it would look if I had set it to auto. I'm pretty sure the other 2 content rows (containing buttons) are the right height either.

Now I hope you guys can help me fix this. I've googled around a bit and I can't seem to find a fitting solution.

Here's the code:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="TBCustomerTitle" Margin="0,0,8,0" FontWeight="Bold" 
               Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Customer:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="TBCustomerData" Grid.Column="1"  
             Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Text="{Binding DisplayedCustomer.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>

    <Line Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">                                 
        <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add a new customer</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}">Update the selected customer</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">Delete the selected customer</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <Line Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">Refresh the list</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding ClearSelectionCommand}">Clear selection</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

**EDIT:** Now with screenshot, as requested. It's the right column I'm talking about (So yes, this UserControl is in itself another nested Grid)

[image: Screenshot of current application]

**EDIT 2:** Here's the containing code. My page consist of three classess.
The 1st (ApplicationView.xaml) is a Window. It has the navigation buttons in the left column, a nice line, and one column containing the view of that specific object. It has no rows.
**ApplicationView.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesRD.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- A DockPanel for the Navigation Buttons-->
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                            
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                Margin="2,5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>

    <Line Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

The view (CustomerView.xaml) is the 2nd file. It is a User control and it also has 3 columns, one with the list of Customers in this case, one for the beautiful seperating line (it is beautiful, right? /sarcasm) and the one I'm struggling with right now with the details and the buttons to do stuff.
Here also no rows.
**CustomerView.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Customer list -->
    <view:CustomerListView Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Line Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />

    <!-- Details -->
    <view:CustomerDetailsView Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you add screenshot as issue is with GUI?

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to my original post @Shadowed

Comment: could you show in an image what the problem is? and what do you want.

Comment: Please add the containing xaml, if it is inside a stackpanel it will not stretch to full height.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I added the containing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `Grid` has two `RowDefinition`s without a height setting. Therefore the default `Height="*"` will be used for both rows. Your inner grid doesn't need two `RowDefinitions`, so removing them should fix your issue. So your inner grid definition should look like this:

```
    <Grid>
        <!--
        remove these row definitions
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="TBCustomerTitle" Margin="0,0,8,0" FontWeight="Bold" 
               Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Customer:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="TBCustomerData" Grid.Column="1"  
             Visibility="{Binding SetVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Text="{Binding DisplayedCustomer.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

**Edit:**

It works for me as expected. The `TextBox` and `TextBlock` get stretched to `2*` height, and the two `StackPanels` have a height of `1*` each. Please provide the XAML where you use your user control. Seems like there lies the problem.

[image: example]

**Edit 2:**

Ah, now I see it. The `VerticalAlignment="Top"` setting in your `CustomerView.xaml` pushes your `CustomerDetailsView` to the top. Either remove this attribute or set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: That's not working for me.   Also, in other classes I do want to add more rows than just 1 row.

Comment: YES that's it! THANK YOU, I really don't know how I could have missed that actually.

Answer (score 1):

The xaml you provided is working fine, the problem is in the containing xaml. Look at this example xaml.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border Background="Yellow">
        <local:MyUserControl/>
    </Border>
    <StackPanel Background="Green">
        <local:MyUserControl/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And the usercontrol (stripped away bindings and styles)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Name="TBCustomerTitle" Margin="0,0,8,0" FontWeight="Bold" >Customer:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="TBCustomerData" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DisplayedCustomer.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>

        <Line Grid.Row="1" Height="5"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add a new customer</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}">Update the selected customer</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">Delete the selected customer</Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <Line Grid.Row="3" Height="5"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">Refresh the list</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ClearSelectionCommand}">Clear selection</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see the usercontrol located in the stackpanel is not stretching because stackpanel does not stretch it's contents.